# How to query for a value when there are multiple values in a single cell (dojo)

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dojox.grid

I have a grid where in one column cell has multiple values for example

lets say i have a column called "Type" in one of the cell there are values like A, B, C...
i am querying the grid like this

```
this.Grid.query = { "TYPE": e.row.data.type };
this.Grid.refresh();
```

so when a user selects a particular TYPE (say A or B..which i have in a dropdown)..the particular rows should be displayed, but what is happening is that I can see the grid data when cell has only one value in it..the rows with multiple TYPES in a cell are not shown...how can i show all those rows wherein the selected type is present???

Any help appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for querying the Grid

```
            grid4.setQuery({  TYPE: '*L*'  });
```

Query support the wild card '*'  & '?' .